# Is there any proxy method that allows an object to get default properties

Tags: javascript

Is there any proxy method that allows an object to get default properties,
So let's say I have an object

```
var item = {
    Value: 123,
    MaxValue: 999,
    MinValue: 0
    }
```

When I use `var def= item`, I can return the value of item.Value (i.e. def =123 instead of the item object) if the other fields are accessed normally

```
var max = item.MaxValue;//999
var min = item.MinValue;//0
var val = item.Value;//123
var def = item; //123
```

Comment: I think you need to override = operator instead of use proxy

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do something like that would be if you were able to coerce the object to a string, for example:

```js
var item = {
  Value: 123,
  MaxValue: 999,
  MinValue: 0,
  toString() {
    return this.Value;
  }
};

var def = '' + item;
console.log(def);
```

Otherwise, you'll have a plain object reference, which will be an object, not a primitive.

Of course, note that with this, `def` will be a string, not a number.